Automount duplicates all mountpoints DOZENS of times
Coming from arch, I am using Ubuntu for a side project, and the automount behaviour is driving me insane. I have two internal hard drives, one with the system on it and a 640G one mounted at /media/rayne/data. This is what I see in the file manager:

The same thing happens whenever I connect an external drive:

And indeed, lsblk lists a bunch of copies of the exact same mount point:

There are no duplicate folders in /media/rayne/, and the permissions on the ext4 file systems are all normal. If I connect the same drive to an arch system and automount it there with nautilus, I get exactly one copy of it instead of fifty.
Ubuntu does this for any and all hard drives I connect, no matter whether I connect them for the first time or the hundredth and no matter whether I have unmounted them correctly the previous time.
I am on Ubuntu 22.04.4 with the default Gnome (seems to be 42.9), and all packages are up to date. This behaviour started the very first time I booted the system after installation.
What is this, and how can I stop it? Nautilus is running seriously slow by now, presumably because it is not supposed to have more than three hundred entries in its sidebar.
